# Block scalar-vector multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large 1-dimensional array `x` which I've got by concatenation of smaller arrays `x_0 ,..., x_m-1` of different length. I also know the list `L` of the length of each `x_i`. Given an array `a` of length `m`, the goal is to compute a flat array `[a[0]*x0, a[1]*x1,...]`.

For example, if I have `x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])` and `a=np.array([2,-1]), L = [2,3]`, then the result should be
`np.array([2,4,-3,-4,-5])`

Is there any simpler (faster, more pythonic, etc.) way to do this in numpy, than this naive implementation?

```
L.insert(0,0)
cs = np.cumsum(L)
y = np.empty(x.shape) 
for i in range(m):
    y[cs[i]:cs[i+1]] = a[i] * x[cs[i]:cs[i+1]]
```

I can also do this in Numba.

`m` is of order of hundreds, the length of each `x_i` is around 1e6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeat elements of `a` with `np.repeat` and perform elementwise multiplication -

```
y = x*np.repeat(a,L)
```

Comment: Seems like that's not faster, but much much simpler.

Comment: @cheyp If each `x_i` is in millions, it might just be better to loop through, because `repeating` would create a similar copy.

Answer (score 1):

**Out of place Numba version**

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def mult(x,a,L):
  out=np.empty(x.shape[0],dtype=x.dtype)
  ii=0
  for i in range(L.shape[0]):
    for j in range(L[i]):
      out[ii]=x[ii]*a[i]
      ii+=1
  return out
```

**In place Numba version**

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def mult(x,a,L):
  ii=0
  for i in range(L.shape[0]):
    for j in range(L[i]):
      x[ii]=x[ii]*a[i]
      ii+=1
  return x
```

**Timings**

```
L=np.random.randint(low=1000,high=2000,size=500)
x=np.random.rand(L.sum())
a=np.random.rand(L.shape[0])

Divakar's version:          6.4ms
Out of place Numba version: 2.8ms
In place Numba version:     1.2ms
```

Please note that the first call to the Numba versions takes longer (compilation overhead).

Comment: Cool, I have got similar benchmarks. Before I combined numba with numpy, but it seems like plain numba (together with `fastmath`) is much better.